# Spring SAML Alias is used both for entity and SP

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml

I am new to SAML, and am integrating it into a Spring web application. I started by following the Spring SAML quick-start guide found here:
   http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html

I got a this running fine. I then wanted to switch to target IDP, which is already running and successfully serving other SPs within the company.

In my securityContext.xml, I added the following to the metadata bean:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.io.File">classpath:security/MyEntityId_sp.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
               <property name="local" value="true"/>
               <property name="alias" value="myAlias"/>
               <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
               <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
               <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
               <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
               <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
               <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
               <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
               <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value type="java.io.File">classpath:security/IDP-MetaData.xml</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>
```

Using the Firefox SAML tracer, I can see that the interactions work fine, and the IDP redirect back to my app (the SP) after authenticating the user, with a  valid SAML XML packet. This is not surprising since this IDP is already successfully being used by other SPs. 
However, it is redirecting to "http://localhost:8080/saml-demo/saml/SSO/alias/myAlias" which in turn throws the following error to the browser...

> ```
>  Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error determining metadata contracts
> ```

Digging into the code a bit further with the Java debugger, I found the real error is deeper in the code. It is thrown by org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager on line 913 when it sees the same alias for both the SP and the IDP. The real error is:

> ```
>  MetadataProviderException: Alias myAlias is used both for entity MyEntityId and MyEntityId
> ```

This only other change beyond what the quick start guide has is to the metadataGeneratorFilter:

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="entityId" value="MyEntityId"/>
            <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The IDP metadata file contains ...

```
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="MyEntityId" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
  <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="0" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>xxxxxx</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" index="0" isDefault="1" />
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" />
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" />
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" />
    <md:ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" />
    <md:ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" />
    <md:ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" />
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" />
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" />
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" />
  </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
  <md:AttributeAuthorityDescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>xxxxxx</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:AttributeService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://auth.myidp.com/sa1234/" />
  </md:AttributeAuthorityDescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Here is the contents of MyEntityId_sp.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    ID="MyEntityId" entityID="MyEntityId">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true"
        WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>xxx</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>xxx</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:SingleLogoutService
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
            Location="http://localhost:8080/saml-demo/saml/SingleLogout/alias/myAlias" />
        <md:SingleLogoutService
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
            Location="http://localhost:8080/saml-demo/saml/SingleLogout/alias/myAlias" />
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
        </md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
        </md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
        </md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
        </md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName
        </md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"
            Location="http://localhost:8080/saml-demo/saml/SSO/alias/myAlias"
            index="0" isDefault="true" />
        <md:AssertionConsumerService
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8080/saml-demo/saml/SSO/alias/myAlias"
            index="1" />
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Comment: You can't have two entities with the same identifier. Not sure if Spring supports the concept of virtual identifiers like some commercial products, which is why this is a comment, not answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew. I changed the EntityID inside the SP's metadata file to something else. So now the IDP has one EntityID and the SP has a different one. When I do that, I get this error instead: "WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl - Our entity is not the intended audience of the assertion". This is why I had both of those configured to the same EntityID, I thought they had to be the same.

Comment: Looking at the SAML tracer in firefox, the final SAML assertion from the IDP does contain:             <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>MyEntityId</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>

Comment: Andrew, your comment was effectively the answer to this issue. I posted more details as an answer to give anyone else who runs into something like this more details. However, you should get credit since your comment was correct, and is what pointed me in the right direction (if for no other reason then it validated for me that everything else I had set up was correct-ish). If you move your comment to an answer I will flag it as the resolution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to track down the issue.

The IDP had an audience restriction that used the same ID ad the EntityID of the IDP itself. I could see this in the IDP meta data file:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="MyEntityId" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
```

Then using the Firefox SAML trace add on I could see the final responce from the IDP contained:

```
<saml:AudienceRestriction> <saml:Audience>MyEntityId</saml:Audience> </saml:AudienceRestriction>
```

Obviously "MyEntityID" is not what was literally used, it was a keyword for this app that made sense in the context of the files. However, this meant I needed to give my SP entity the same ID as this AudienceRestriction, or else I would get an error. However, As Andrew K. pointed out, you cannot give two entities the same entity ID.

I was not the one to set up the IDP server, so I do not have control over some of this (and the IDP metadata file was provided to me, so I just assumed there was nothign wrong with it). However, to solve this, I simply changed the entityID in the IDP metadata file. I'm new to SAML, but I don't think this will have any negative impacts for my specific implementation.